# Select entity by property / User by username

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

i have the FOSUserBundle installed.
Now i would like to select all users via `<select />` box.

For example i have...

```
<?php
// [...]
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('favorite_drink')
            ->add('favorite_meal')
            ->add('favorite_film')
            // Problem...
            ->add('bestFriend', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeDemoUserBundle:User',
                'property' => 'id'
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

The entity with bestFriend relation.

```
<?php
// [...]
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="favorite_drink", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $favorite_drink;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="favorite_meal", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $favorite_meal;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="favorite_film", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $favorite_film;

    /**
     * @var \AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $bestFriend;

    // [...]
}
```

On submit i get the error that "Validation Failed".

Expected thing like this:

[image: the expected result]

And in background:

[image: the background expected result]

What should i do?
Any tips? :)

Comment: Can you post your entity with relation `bestFriend` ?

Comment: How are you theming this form element?

Comment: Show your `DemoUserBundle/User.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's due to the `User` validation. You could deep into `User` validation and let the `:` and `(` symbols in the `name` field.

Or you can just try to replace `No best friend :(` with `No best friend`

Comment: Then i have the same problem. I used a transformator now: FOS\UserBundle\Form\DataTransformer\UserToUsernameTransformer
thats what i want :)